# How to set the latitude and longitude of the VisibleRegion programmatically when the GoogleMap loads?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, latitude-longitude

I am working on GoogleMap. I need to set the latitude and longitude corresponding to the four corners of the GoogleMap which is currently visible to me on my android device screen.

We can get the those values using,
map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().farLeft;

for the current zoom level.

But i want to know if there's any method to set the value for farLeft,nearRight,etc programitacally keeping the zoom level unchanged.

Any help aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw an invisible rectangle that is the size of map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion() and then set the camera to be the size of the rectangle, it could work.

Is keeping the zoom level the same really so important? It could just work by adjusting the zoom level somehow.